# Ruby: print the code of an arbitrary method (and exec in context)

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, exec

I would like to do something like the following:

```
class String
  def fancy_thing appendix
   # Just a trivial example to ensure self and params work.
   # Pretend this is something complex.
   self.reverse + appendix
  end
end

# print_method on instance or class should spit out a string
#  containing the actual code for that method
ft_code = "cob".print_method :fancy_thing
ft_code = String.print_instance_method :fancy_thing
  # => "{|appendix| self.reverse + appendix }"  *

# ft_code gets passed around a bit...

# exec on an object should run code (w/ parameters) as if that code is 
#  an instance method on that object (or class method if it's a class)
"cob".exec(ft_code, '!') #=> "boc!"
```

How might one code print_method and foo.exec? Preferably, they should work for any arbitrary methods, without knowing a priori where they might happen to have been defined or sourced from.

- Yes, I know methods and blocks aren't completely the same. But this is closer to what yield and call would normally take; I don't know of a better solution.

Comment: you shouldn't need "cob" in both those places to print that output. can you revise/clarify the question on what each of those methods do...

Comment: Per my comment on joshng's solution, the purpose is a) for irb/console purposes (outside of the debugger proper) and b) just to see if it's possible. See edits for what they do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

parse_tree will give you the key step that you'll need:

http://github.com/seattlerb/parsetree/tree/master

I think this does it, in the quickest/hackiest/most insecure manner possible:

```
require 'parse_tree'
require 'parse_tree_extensions'
require 'ruby2ruby'

class Object
  def method_source(name)
    (class << self; self; end).instance_method(name).to_ruby
  end

  def exec(ruby, *args)
    code = eval(ruby, binding)
    code.call(*args)
  end
end
```

I'll add that I'm having difficulty seeing how this is a good idea...  But there you have it. :-)

[edit]

Also note that your example is busted: your 'fancy_thing' method requires an argument (appendix).

[edit 2]

going over the top, here's your test code with bugs fixed (the way I think you wanted it):

```
class String
  def fancy_thing(appendix)
    reverse << appendix || nil
  end
end

code = "cob".method_source :fancy_thing
# => "proc {|appendix| reverse << appendix }"  *
"cob".exec code, '!'
# => "boc!"
```

Comment: My intent for it is in irb / rails console, for easy debugging, method editing, etc (when not necessarily in the debugger proper).

And just because I'm curious whether it can be *done* in 1.8 / 1.9. ;-)

Comment: Fixed the method in OP. Part of the point of its definition though was to use 'self', as a test to ensure that exec had it bound properly. But 's really just a random example.

Now I wonder how parse_tree and ruby2ruby work that magic to_ruby call. Looks like I'll need to read their code. ;)

Comment: Your solution is pretty good, but fails for two things. 1) class methods; 2) built-ins (e.g. "foo".print_method :to_s # => UnsupportedNodeError). I wonder if that's fixable.

Comment: ok, edited my answer to support class-methods. also renamed the 'print_method' to better reflect what it's doing: returning the method_source.

Unfortunately, it won't be possible to access the source for most built-in methods, because they are written in C.

Now, could you please click the little check-mark next to my answer?    :-)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very easy to implement without just reading the Ruby file and searching for the method code. In Ruby 1.8, you could use ParseTree and ruby2ruby. In 1.9, I don't know of any solution.